# Cannot evaluate script arguments from function

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments, bash4

I've started writing shell scripts again and I've found myself in a situation where I frequently have to write debug echo's to trace what the script is doing. The, easy, way I used to do this right was to write something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
myVar = 'Erractic Nonesense'
echo "myVar: $myVar"
```

==> `myVar: Erractic Nonesense`

This worked great and was fairly simple but, having to write this for every variable I wished to trace was tiring and as a person who thinks that having less code to do more stuff is great, I wrote myself a function:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbg() # $msg
{
    echo "$@: ${!@}" 
}

myVar = 'Erractic Nonesense'
dbg myVar
```

==> `myVar: Erractic Nonesense`

This works great for regular variables but, for the scripts arguments ($1, $2, etc.), does not work. Why?

==> `$ ./myScript 123`

```
#!/bin/bash
...
dbg 1 # This is the bugger in question.
```

==> `1: 1`

And also, how can this be circumvented?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Barmar I now see why it behaves this way but, the second question remains.

**EDIT 2**

Using koodawg idea, this is the result. It works. *Updated, see **EDIT 4***

**EDIT 3**

I think that a mix of **EDIT 2** and `set +-x` will be a viable solution.

**EDIT 4**

Updated the logic to fall on arguments as the previous one did not always worked. Added fancy tabs.

```
RX_INTEGER='^[0-9]+$'
DBG_SCRIPT_ARGS=( "$0" "$@" )
DBG_PADDING="        " # tabs of 8 spaces
dbg() # $msg | OUT$args OUT$res
{    
    args=$@
    [[ $args =~ $RX_INTEGER ]] && res="${DBG_SCRIPT_ARGS[args]}" || res="${!@}"
    printf "%s%s\`%s\`\n" "$args:" "${DBG_PADDING:$(((${#args}-1)%${#DBG_PADDING}))}" 
}
```

Comment: Tried this? Enable debugging by putting 'set -x' in your script - prints out all commands as executed.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for reminding me that one existed! The only only problem now is reading the huge mess it outputs... I'm still curious as to why my function doesn't work though.

Comment: Inside the function, `$1`, `$2`, etc. refer to the function's arguments, not the original script's arguments.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `function XXX {` syntax to define functions, use the standard `XXX() {` syntax.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this particular case? And I'll remove 'function' in my future scripts. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You could do 'export MYARGS=$*' at the top of your script to capture your command line then you can use MYARGS inside your function.

Comment: @MomemtumMori you can disable debugging again with `'set +x`, that way you will have less garbage output, to debug only the interesting sections.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to call the function and explicitly pass the script args to it.  You could do something like:

```
for argz in `echo $*`
do
    dbg ${argz}
done
```